# Relying on compiler optimization of multiple static cast calls?

Tags: c++, optimization, static-cast

I'm working with a code base where I see the following lines of code

```
  auto a = static_cast<custom_type*>(obj.get())->a();
  auto b = static_cast<custom_type*>(obj.get())->b();
  auto c = static_cast<custom_type*>(obj.get())->c();
```

Is it reasonable to expect that the compiler would optimize the series of `get()` and `static_cast` calls, or would it be better to do something such as:

```
  auto temp = static_cast<custom_type*>(obj.get());
  auto a = temp->a();
  auto b = temp->b();
  auto c = temp->c();
```

Comment: The compiler has no way of knowing that multiple calls to `get` return the same object, so in your 2 examples the behaviour is different.

Comment: Sean is correct. If you can guarantee, that the (`shared_ptr`?) does not change, the second version is a little faster, because it only has to access the object once. The cost of static_cast is negligible in this context. So: No, the compiler does not optimize anything here, because, in a multithreaded context, the contents of `obj` might change between calls.

Comment: @Sean Oh I see. Even though there's nothing in between lines 1 & 2, the compiler wouldn't know that `obj` remains unchanged and therefore `get()` would produce the same thing in both lines?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Ah I see. I think you answered my follow up question to Sean. If the compiler were able to optimize the additional calls away, would there be a situation in which the 1st would be faster? I'm not sure what the overhead is in creating an actual l-value (`temp`)

Comment: @Sean Generally yes, in specific case that `get` is a simple inlined getter matter differs, though... But even if it was I don't recommend relying on compiler optimisations (at least not in such simple cases as the given one) – code of `get` might change some day.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Who talked about a `shared_ptr`? The `obj` might be *anything*...

Comment: @student010101 -- The only entity that knows whether declaring a `temp` variable is equivalent is the programmer.  The compiler's optimizer may not do anything with the code, since there can be side-effects all over the place with the intervening function calls to `get()`, `a()`, `b()`, `c()`, etc.  Maybe an optimizer can do global optimizations, possible, but I wouldn't hang my hat on this being the case.

Comment: @Aconcagua That's what the `?` in (`shared_ptr`) was for. I was making an assumption due to the lack of information.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium hopefully `unique_ptr`, that (should be) the owning pointer type for 99% of situations

Comment: @RefugnicEternium Point is that if the assumption fails your statement potentially is not correct any more...

Comment: @Sean The compiler absolutely has a way of determining if the `get` returns the same object, it's called global optimization, and when it is able to determine that the return value won't change it will almost always try to optimize for that. This looks like it's invoking the `get` on a smart pointer, which is templated, which means that its definition has to be available to compiler.

Answer (score 5):

`static_cast<T>` is not a function.

Depending on the relationship between `custom_type*` and `decltype(obj.get())`, and whether `a`, `b` or `c` are virtual, there might be no trace of it in the resulting object code, depending on how the implementation has chosen to implement member function calls.

If the compiler can prove that `obj.get()` will return the same value each time, and it has no other observable effects, then it might do something equivalent to your second snipped, by the as-if rule.

Answer (score 2):

In general no. Not based on the information provided in your quesiton.

From the code you posted alone you cannot tell if the two snippets are the same. One reason is that conversion operators can be overloaded and can have side effects. Consider this contrived example (for brevity I omitted the `get`, but the idea is the same, perform 3 times the same `static_cast`):

```
#include <iostream>

struct custom_type {};

struct foo {
    operator custom_type* () {
        std::cout << "x\n";
        return nullptr;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo a;
    auto c = static_cast<custom_type*>(a);
    auto d = static_cast<custom_type*>(a);
    auto e = static_cast<custom_type*>(a);
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/ErzKd1Yre) is:

```
x
x
x
```

Which is different from the output of your "optimized" variant. The compiler may optimize it when it can prove that observable behavior is the same. However, when this is the case then it doesn't matter which variant you write down (because the compiler will know that they are equiavalent).

This is only considering the `static_cast`, though similarly the call to `get` might have side effects such that calling it once does not result in same observable behavior than calling it three times. And even if it does, the compiler would need to proove that before it is allowed to perform the desired optimization.

Comment: *'No.'* should rather be *'In general: no.'* – as there are situations where the compiler actually *can* do so (e.g `obj.get()` already returning a pointer and being a simple inlined getter – provided I recall correctly multi-threading not being considered in this context...).

Comment: Multithreading is not a factor in optimizations like this, unless you specify `volatile`.